# Problem with BAM huawei linux mobile partner

Tags: networking, internet, minimize

After minimizing the Huawei Linux Mobile Partner window I can't restore it. Commonly it minimizes to tray, but then it vanishes (but the connection still work). What can I do?
  (Distributor ID:  Ubuntu | 
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04 | 
Release:    13.04 | 
Codename:   raring | 
unity 7.0.0 )

[image: Example Screenshot]

Ubuntu is amd64 version, but the BAM Huawei Linux Mobile Partner is for i386 version, it didn't open before installation ia32-libs

Comment: Edit your question with your Ubuntu and Unity version. Type `lsb_release -a` and `unity --version` respectively on a terminal to find this out.

Comment: added! Ubuntu 13.04 and unity 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond the solution: `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`