# Uget tray icon not showing

Tags: 13.10, system-tray, uget

Since I upgraded to Saucy, Uget is not showing in the system tray, although the **Always show tray icon** option in Uget settings is checked.
This happens only with Uget, all my other apps have working tray icons (vlc,qbittorrent..)

[image]

`sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`:

```
rc  account-plugin-generic-oauth                   0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1                  i386         GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon - generic OAuth
rc  appmenu-gtk:i386                               12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1               i386         Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  appmenu-gtk3:i386                              12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1               i386         Export GTK menus over DBus
rc  arora                                          0.11.0-0ubuntu1                             i386         simple cross platform web browser
rc  buc                                            0.5.2-20                                    i386         BUC
rc  clementine                                     1.1.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1                         i386         modern music player and library organizer
rc  epiphany-browser                               3.6.1-2ubuntu1                              i386         Intuitive GNOME web browser
rc  epiphany-browser-data                          3.6.1-2ubuntu3                              all          Data files for the GNOME web browser
rc  fancontrol                                     1:3.3.3-1ubuntu1                            all          utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
rc  flaremonitor                                   1.0-5                                       i386         It is an advanced browser integration helper module of FlareGet
rc  google-chrome-stable                           28.0.1500.95-r213514                        i386         The web browser from Google
rc  hal                                            0.5.14-8ubuntu1                             i386         Hardware Abstraction Layer
rc  hotot-gtk                                      1:0.9.8.5+git20120630.884797d-1             all          lightweight microblogging client - GTK+ wrapper
rc  jockey-common                                  0.9.7-0ubuntu13                             all          user interface and desktop integration for driver management
rc  libanalitza4abi1                               4:4.10.4-0ubuntu0.1                         i386         library to work with mathematical expressions
rc  libanalitza5                                   4:4.11.2-0ubuntu1                           i386         library to  work with mathematical expressions
rc  libanalitzagui4abi2                            4:4.10.4-0ubuntu0.1                         i386         library to work with mathematical expressions - GUI routines
rc  libanalitzaplot4                               4:4.10.4-0ubuntu0.1                         i386         library to work with mathematical expressions - plot routines
rc  libavcodec53:i386                              6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2                            i386         Libav codec library
rc  libavutil51:i386                               6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2                            i386         Libav utility library
rc  libbamf3-1:i386                                0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1           i386         Window matching library - shared library
rc  libboost-iostreams1.49.0                       1.49.0-4                                    i386         Boost.Iostreams Library
rc  libboost-program-options1.49.0                 1.49.0-4                                    i386         program options library for C++
rc  libboost-python1.49.0                          1.49.0-4                                    i386         Boost.Python Library
rc  libboost-thread1.49.0                          1.49.0-4                                    i386         portable C++ multi-threading
rc  libbrlapi0.5:i386                              4.4-8ubuntu4                                i386         braille display access via BRLTTY - shared library
rc  libcamel-1.2-40                                3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                            i386         Evolution MIME message handling library
rc  libcolumbus0-0                                 0.4.0daily13.04.16~13.04-0ubuntu1           i386         error tolerant matching engine - shared library
rc  libdns95                                       1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                  i386         DNS Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libdvbpsi7                                     0.2.2-1                                     i386         library for MPEG TS and DVB PSI tables decoding and generating
rc  libebackend-1.2-5                              3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                            i386         Utility library for evolution data servers
rc  libechonest2.0:i386                            2.0.2-0ubuntu1                              i386         Qt library for communicating with The Echo Nest platform
rc  libechonest2.1:i386                            2.1.0-2                                     i386         Qt library for communicating with The Echo Nest platform
rc  libedata-book-1.2-15                           3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                            i386         Backend library for evolution address books
rc  libedata-cal-1.2-18                            3.6.4-0ubuntu1.1                            i386         Backend library for evolution calendars
rc  libftgl2                                       2.1.3~rc5-4ubuntu1                          i386         library to render text in OpenGL using FreeType
rc  libgc1c3:i386                                  1:7.2d-0ubuntu5                             i386         conservative garbage collector for C and C++
rc  libgnome-desktop-3-4                           3.6.3-0ubuntu1                              i386         Utility library for loading .desktop files - runtime files
rc  libgtksourceview-3.0-0:i386                    3.6.3-0ubuntu1                              i386         shared libraries for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
rc  libgweather-3-1                                3.6.2-0ubuntu1                              i386         GWeather shared library
rc  libhal-storage1                                0.5.14-8ubuntu1                             i386         Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library for storage devices
rc  libhal1                                        0.5.14-8ubuntu1                             i386         Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library
rc  libharfbuzz0:i386                              0.9.13-1                                    i386         OpenType text shaping engine
rc  libhd16                                        16.0-2.2                                    i386         Hardware identification system library
rc  libibus-1.0-0:i386                             1.4.2-0ubuntu2                              i386         Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
rc  libical0                                       0.48-2                                      i386         iCalendar library implementation in C (runtime)
rc  libimobiledevice3                              1.1.4-1ubuntu6.2                            i386         Library for communicating with the iPhone and iPod Touch
rc  libisc92                                       1:9.9.2.dfsg.P1-2ubuntu2.1                  i386         ISC Shared Library used by BIND
rc  libkdegamesprivate1                            4:4.10.2-0ubuntu1                           i386         private shared library for KDE games
rc  libkeybinder0                                  0.3.0-1ubuntu1                              i386         registers global key bindings for applications
rc  libkgapi0:i386                                 0.4.4-0ubuntu1                              i386         Google API library for KDE
rc  liblastfm1:i386                                1.0.7-2                                     i386         Last.fm web services library
rc  libnetfilter-queue1                            1.0.2-1                                     i386         Netfilter netlink-queue library
rc  libnl1:i386                                    1.1-7ubuntu1                                i386         library for dealing with netlink sockets
rc  libossp-uuid16                                 1.6.2-1.3                                   i386         OSSP uuid ISO-C and C++ - shared library
rc  libpackagekit-glib2-14:i386                    0.7.6-3ubuntu1                              i386         Library for accessing PackageKit using GLib
rc  libpoppler28:i386                              0.20.5-1ubuntu3                             i386         PDF rendering library
rc  libprojectm2                                   2.1.0+dfsg-1build1                          i386         Advanced Milkdrop-compatible music visualization library
rc  libqxt-core0:i386                              0.6.1-7                                     i386         extensions to Qt core classes (LibQxt)
rc  libqxt-gui0:i386                               0.6.1-7                                     i386         extensions to Qt GUI classes (LibQxt)
rc  libraw5:i386                                   0.14.7-0ubuntu1.13.04.2                     i386         raw image decoder library
rc  librhythmbox-core6                             2.98-0ubuntu5                               i386         support library for the rhythmbox music player
rc  librhythmbox-core7                             3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1                          i386         support library for the rhythmbox music player
rc  libsnmp15                                      5.4.3~dfsg-2.7ubuntu1                       i386         SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
rc  libsqlite0                                     2.8.17-8fakesync1                           i386         SQLite shared library
rc  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1                            4.2.0-0ubuntu1                              i386         Ubuntu One synchronization daemon library
rc  libtiff4:i386                                  3.9.7-2ubuntu1                              i386         Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library (old version)
rc  libunity-core-6.0-5                            7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1           i386         Core library for the Unity interface.
rc  libva-wayland1:i386                            1.2.1-0ubuntu0~raring                       i386         Video Acceleration (VA) API for Linux -- Wayland runtime
rc  libwayland0:i386                               1.0.5-0ubuntu1                              i386         wayland compositor infrastructure - shared libraries
rc  libwebp2:i386                                  0.1.3-3                                     i386         Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic                   3.8.0-19.30                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic                   3.8.0-21.32                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-22-generic                   3.8.0-22.33                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-26-generic                   3.8.0-26.38                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic                   3.8.0-27.40                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.9.0-030900-generic               3.9.0-030900.201304291257                   i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.9.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.9.0-030900rc8-generic            3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835                i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.9.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic             3.8.0-19.30                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-21-generic             3.8.0-21.32                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-22-generic             3.8.0-22.33                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-26-generic             3.8.0-26.38                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-27-generic             3.8.0-27.40                                 i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  preload                                        0.6.4-2                                     i386         adaptive readahead daemon
rc  steam-launcher                                 1.0.0.39                                    all          Launcher for the Steam software distribution service
rc  super-boot-manager                             0.7.15                                      all          Simple gui to configure Grub2, Burg and Plymouth.
rc  totem                                          3.6.3-0ubuntu6                              i386         Simple media player for the GNOME desktop based on GStreamer
rc  transmission-gtk                               2.77-0ubuntu1                               i386         lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK interface)
rc  unity-common                                   7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1           all          Common files for the Unity interface.
rc  vino                                           3.6.2-0ubuntu4                              i386         VNC server for GNOME
rc  wicd-daemon                                    1.7.2.4-4.1                                 all          wired and wireless network manager - daemon
rc  wicd-gtk                                       1.7.2.4-4.1                                 all          wired and wireless network manager - GTK+ client
rc  xscreensaver                                   5.15-2ubuntu1                               i386         Automatic screensaver for X
rc  xscreensaver-data                              5.15-3ubuntu1                               i386         data files to be shared among screensaver frontends
```

`sudo dpkg -l | grep uget`:

```
ii  uget                                           1.10.3-1                                    i386         easy-to-use download manager written in GTK+
```

`sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`:

```
ii  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1                       12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2             i386         Typelib files for libappindicator3-1.
ii  gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1                            12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1             i386         indicator for synchronisation processes status - bindings
ii  indicator-applet-complete                      12.10.2+13.10.20130924.2-0ubuntu1           i386         Clone of the GNOME panel indicator applet
ii  indicator-application                          12.10.1daily13.01.25-0ubuntu1               i386         Application Indicators
ii  indicator-appmenu                              13.01.0+13.10.20130930-0ubuntu1             i386         Indicator for application menus.
ii  indicator-bluetooth                            0.0.6+13.10.20131016-0ubuntu1               i386         System bluetooth indicator.
ii  indicator-datetime                             13.10.0+13.10.20131023.2-0ubuntu1           i386         Simple clock
ii  indicator-keyboard                             0.0.0+13.10.20131010.1-0ubuntu1             i386         Keyboard indicator
ii  indicator-messages                             13.10.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1             i386         indicator that collects messages that need a response
ii  indicator-multiload                            0.3-0ubuntu1                                i386         Graphical system load indicator for CPU, ram, etc.
ii  indicator-power                                12.10.6+13.10.20131008-0ubuntu1             i386         Indicator showing power state.
ii  indicator-printers                             0.1.7daily13.03.01-0ubuntu1                 i386         indicator showing active print jobs
ii  indicator-session                              12.10.5+13.10.20131023.1-0ubuntu1           i386         indicator showing session management, status and user switching
ii  indicator-sound                                12.10.2+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1             i386         System sound indicator.
ii  indicator-sync                                 12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1             i386         indicator for synchronisation processes status
ii  libappindicator1                               12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2             i386         Application Indicators
ii  libappindicator3-1                             12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2             i386         Application Indicators
ii  libindicator3-7                                12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2             i386         panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libindicator7                                  12.10.2+13.10.20130913-0ubuntu2             i386         panel indicator applet - shared library
ii  libsync-menu1:i386                             12.10.5+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1             i386         indicator for synchronisation processes status - libraries
ii  python-appindicator                            12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu2             i386         Python bindings for libappindicator
ii  sni-qt:i386                                    0.2.6-0ubuntu1                              i386         indicator support for Qt
ii  telepathy-indicator                            0.3.1daily13.06.19-0ubuntu1                 i386         Desktop service to integrate Telepathy with the messaging menu.
```

Comment: Did you tried to re-install it? To re-install: `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall uget`. If it doesn't work then try to remove it first then install again. Reply..

Comment: i already tried reinstalling,removing, but it didn't change anything, the official ppa has builds only till raring

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of these commands: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"` and `sudo dpkg -l | grep uget`.

Comment: OMG! You've a lot of **residual** packages. I'm in dilemma now how to solve this issue. Any way let me post the answer, hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to fix this

It seems that the build in the Ubuntu repositories is causing the problem, and when upgraded, Uget (1.10.3-0)was upgraded to the version in the Ubuntu repository (1.10.3-1)

I removed  uget :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge uget
```

Then removed the config files :

```
rm -rf '/home/abdou/.config/uGet'
```

Downloaded & installed the version in the official site :

```
wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/138646189/uget_1.10.3-0ubuntu0%7Eraring_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i uget_1.10.3-0ubuntu0~raring_i386.deb
```

Comment: the problem is the ubuntu repo ignored every attempt we made to update the app...and just pulled in the Debian package. Debian doesn't use appindicator so because of that Ubuntu pulled in a package that didn't include it thus the lack of system tray applet.

Comment: "Downloaded & installed the version in the official site" how on earth is "launchpadlibrarian" the official site? The official site is http://ugetdm.com

Answer (score 1):

uGet does not have an official 13.10 version yet but we are working on a version for it. However, the repo of 13.10 has finally been updated to 1.10.3 so if you uninstalled and reinstalled from the Ubuntu repo then it will work. Ubuntu's Repo ignored our requests and just pulled in Debian package which they removed the appindicator support which Ubuntu needs.

Ubuntu 13.10 was the first time Ubuntu actually updated uGet in the repo. 13.04 now has a backport but right now only it has a backport.

uGet currently only has official support for 13.04-12.04 but we will be releasing a 13.10 version as soon as possible.

Comment: I guess i'll have to wait till the next version is out!

Comment: uGet 1.10.4 is fixed in Ubuntu 14.04 but 13.10 is still outdated but the PPA and the DEB from the official site is now up to date. - http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use this program from https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sni-qt/ ; or use the terminal `sudo apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:i386` ;

This program must solve the problem of system tray with programs' icons.

Comment: `sni-qt` is already installed.

Comment: try this solution (I don't know other) : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html

Comment: Nope, that didn't help! the build is for raring, it says [here](http://ugetdm.com/downloads) that there is no saucy builds so i'll just wait till the next version is out,thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry I could not help, maybe one another will help you. )

Comment: I have the same problem with other program and I can't solve it.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/355323/problem-with-bam-huawei-linux-mobile-partner

Answer (score 0):

First remove all **residual packages** using this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Then try to install `appmenu-gtk` , `appmenu-gtk3`, `indicator-application`,`indicator-appmenu`,`indicator-applet-complete` if removed accidently:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-applet-complete
```

Watch carefully the messages given while install, as it may the clue to solve the problem. Also be sure that while installing, non of the packages are going to be removed.

Logout/Restart

Reply if something goes wrong..

---

**Edit**

**It is clear that you've got a bug.**

So it is good to launch a bug and help the developer to acquaint about it.

There is a good post here which will give you all the information to launch the bug:

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

And yes you can report bugs related to **Uget** here:

http://ugetdm.com/reportbug

<sub>Thanks to [Michael Tunnell](https://askubuntu.com/users/72652/michael-tunnell) to tell about this link.</sub>

Comment: all tha residual packages were removed, installed the packages, but still no icon!

Comment: Now I'll only ask: Are you sure that the option `Always show tray icon` is checked under **edit-> Settings-> UISettings**? Also post the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator`. Reply..

Comment: i'm 100% sure that it's checked, here is a [screenshot](http://www.mediafire.com/view/wzzd7ae04x5ed4e#), as for the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep indicator` i'll add it to the question.

Comment: Now you proved that everything is fine! It is looking weird now! I don't know what is the problem.. I'm stuck now!

Comment: @ArK, I think this is a bug. You should launch a bug. But before this, if you've any other desktop environment installed like `gnome` or `kde` or `cinnamon` any thing else, try to open it and check whether you've the same problem? Reply..

Comment: Tested on `XFCE` & `KDE`, the tray icon works fine, so i guess this is a bug with the unity desktop, i don't really know how to launch a bug so if you can show me how.

Comment: @ArK: I've edited my answer!

Comment: we prefer bugs to be made on our website...not on various distro specific sites. Please edit your link to the official link of http://ugetdm.com/reportbug

Comment: @MichaelTunnell: Thanks for your link.. I've mentioned the link..